# Alter a table based on data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a main table as ,lets say TABLE1

```
PLANT        JUNCTION     COST    Disct
LONDON        LD_1         10   1
LONDON        LD_2         11   2
LONDON        LD_3         12   5
SUTHERLAND    TE_R10       8    20
SUTHERLAND    TE_R10       8    20
SUTHERLAND    TE_R10       8    20
SUTHERLAND    TE_R11       9    23
SUTHERLAND    TE_R12      10    29
NY            TE_R8        2    5
NY            TE_R8        2    5
NY            TE_R9       11    10
```

I have another table Table2 like this :

```
PLANT         JUNCTION  FLATRATE
SUTHERLAND     TE_R10   0
NY             TE_R8    10
```

My intention is to generate a table like the below one from table 1 and table2  :

```
PLANT   JUNCTION    CARRIERCOST Disct
LONDON      LD_1    10  1
LONDON      LD_2    11  2
LONDON      LD_3    12  5
SUTHERLAND  TE_R10  0   20
SUTHERLAND  TE_R10  0   20
SUTHERLAND  TE_R10  0   20
SUTHERLAND  TE_R11  9   23
SUTHERLAND  TE_R12  10  29
NY          TE_R8   10  5
NY          TE_R8   10  5
NY          TE_R9   11  10
```

That is if the plant name and junction name from the table2 matches with table1 , then update the table1's COST to the FLATRATE of table2

Comment: Good luck! Or do you actually have a question/problem?

Comment: So, do you need a new table created or just want to update an existing one. Also update or alter?

Comment: MySQL, Oracle, or both? If it is not both, please edit your post and remove the inapplicable tag. It really only takes two seconds.

Answer (score 0):

**MySQl**

```
UPDATE T
SET S.Cost = ISNULL(T.COST,S.Cost)
FROM Table1 S
LEFT JOIN Table2 T ON S.PLANT = T.PLANT AND S.PLANT ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle**

```
CREATE TABLE table3
AS
   SELECT a.plant, a.junction, NVL (b.flatrate, a.cost) carriercost, a.disct
     FROM table1 a 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 b ON a.plant = b.plant AND a.junction = b.junction
```